# Parse Bootstrap Date Range Picker value in Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a bootstrap date range picker input which gives a value similar to something like this:

```
  "dateRange" => "19 Nov 2017 - 18 Dec 2017"
```

I need to parse this value in my Controller and get two dates out of it. Start date and end date. (Preferably using `Carbon`)

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: string manipulation then date manipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `explode()` for this([DEMO](https://eval.in/920866)):

```
$dates = explode(' - ', '19 Nov 2017 - 18 Dec 2017');
var_dump($dates);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending answer by @mega6382, you could parse the dates after exploding them

```
$dates = explode(' - ', '19 Nov 2017 - 18 Dec 2017');
$start_date = Carbon::parse($dates[0]);
$end_date = Carbon::parse($dates[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$date  = explode('-',"19 Nov 2017 - 18 Dec 2017");// dateRange is you string
$dateFrom = $date[0];
$dateTo = $date[1];
$DateNew= strtotime( $dateFrom );
echo $dateFrom = date( 'Y-m-d', $DateNew);
$DateNew= strtotime( $dateTo );
echo $dateTo = date( 'Y-m-d', $DateNew);
```